# Specify type of a TaggedOutput to pass through GroupByKey (as a part of CombinePerKey)

Tags: python-3.7, apache-beam, python-3.8, type-hinting

When I tried to migrate my project based on apache beam pipelines from python 3.7 to 3.8 the type hint check started to fail at this place:

```
pcoll = (
    wrong_pcoll,
    some_pcoll_1,
    some_pcoll_2,
    some_pcoll_3,
) | beam.Flatten(pipeline=pipeline)
pcoll | beam.CombinePerKey(MyCombineFn())  # << here
```

with this error:

```
apache_beam.typehints.decorators.TypeCheckError: Input type hint violation at GroupByKey: expected Tuple[TypeVariable[K], TypeVariable[V]], got Union[TaggedOutput, Tuple[Any, Any], Tuple[Any, _MyType1], Tuple[Any, _MyType2]]
```

The `wrong_pcoll` is actually a TaggedOutput because it's received as a tagged output from one on previous ptransforms.

Type hint check fails when the type of `wrong_pcoll` which is a TaggedOutput as a part of the type of `pcoll` (which type in correspondence with the exception is `Union[TaggedOutput, Tuple[Any, Any], Tuple[Any, _MyType1], Tuple[Any, _MyType2]]`) passed to GrouByKey that is used inside of CombinePerKey.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does it work in python 3.7 and doesn't on 3.8?
2. How to specify type for a tagged output? I tried to specify the type for the `process()` method of PTransform that produced that as a union of all output types that it yields, but for some reason for the type hint check has been chose the wrong one. Then I specified strictly the type I need: `Tuple[Any, Any]` and it has worked. But it's not a way since `process()` also yields other types, like simple `str`.

As a workaround, I can pass this `wrong_pcoll` through a simple `beam.Map` with `lambda x: x` and `.with_output_types(Tuple[Any, Any])`, but it does not seem to be a clear way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated similar failures recently.

Beam has some type-inferencing capabilities which rely on opcode analysis of pipeline code. Inferencing is somewhat limited and conservative. For example, when Beam attempts to infer a function's return type and encounters an opcode that it does not know, Beam infers the return type as `Any`.  It is also sensitive to Python minor version.

1. Python 3.8 removed some opcodes, such as `SETUP_LOOP`, that Beam didn't handle previously. Therefore, type inference behavior kicked in for some portions of the code where it didn't work before. I've seen pipelines where an increased type inference on Python 3.8 exposed incorrectly-specified hints.
2. You are running into a bug/limitation in Beam's type inference for multi-output DoFns tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4132. There was some progress, but it's not completely addressed. As a workaround you could manually specify the hints. I think `beam.Flatten().with_output_types(Tuple[str, Union[_MyType1, _MyType2]])` should work for your case.